# Basename in JSP?

Tags: jsp

So, I've been scripting in PHP for a while and I now have to translate the code to JSP. However, the issue I am having aside from many things is: the function basename in PHP isn't in JSP. What I've tried is

```
<?php
request.getHeader("referer").getName();
```

I get am error because the String class doesn't have getName().
I am trying to extract the filename of the URL of the referring page. So if you visted the site page from 'http://www.test.com/hello.htm', you will get 'hello.htm'

I'm not trying to receive it as a CGI variable. It is only a small part of my code. I'm extracting information from a filesystem based on the refering url. In PHP the code started out like this:

```
$parent = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

If there isn't a function, I guessing regular expressino would work. I'll just have to delve into Java's list of reg exp syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensive list of request context vars: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSTL/JSTLPrintPageContext.htm